# PSQL timezones and select query

Tags: psql, postgresql-8.3

I am currently stuck on trying to get some results from a database due to different timezones and the way the records are kept.  It is a table that has 4 columns: timestamp, recordid, name, accountnumber.
When I run a simple query:

```
Select * from table;
```

I get the results that I need but the timestamp field is in GMT time.

What I am trying to run is a query to get the last 30 minutes of records with:

```
Select * from table where timestamp::time >= (Current_time - interval '30 minutes') and timestamp::time < (current_time);
```

but from this query, I get 0 records returned, even though I know that it should be there.

I have tried to convert both fields to UTC, using "at time zone 'UTC'" command, also tried using now() instead of current_time.

I have now been working on this for 2 days, so I am running out of time and patience - any help would be appreciated.  I am running version 8.3.

Regards,

Comment: For debugging, if you `SET TimeZone = 'UTC'` do you then get the result you expect?

Comment: Thank you for the note.  As this is a production Database with a web reporting tool that most end users have access to, will this cause any issues with the data and what they see?  As I do not have access to the webpage code, I dont know how it goes from this UTC time in the database to the local date/time that appears on the webpage.

Comment: Don't do it in `postgresql.conf`, do it per-session for testing purposes. I'm not suggesting this as a long run solution, hence "for debugging...", but just as a test.

Comment: Thanks Craig - in doing this per session, I was able to get the records required, but in UTC, not local timezone (Australian/ACT).  If that is going to be the output, then I will let the people who need the data convert it.